AnyLogic FluidSelectOutput for many outputs
Does anyone know how can I create a logic as Select Output In/Select Output Out using FluidSelectOutput or something like that that works for Fluid Library?
I'm creating a simulation of a tank that can deliver for a number X of clients that must be input, but I'm having a problem creating the logic

If the requested is a single connection between two fluid flows, in this case the expected way is to use FluidEnter and FluidExit pairs. This way, you can connect one of several inputs (each ending in their respective FluidExit) to a single FluidEnter input.
The same could be done if you want to connect one flow (with its FluidExit) to any number of several outputs (each with their respective FluidEnter)

The [FluidSelectOutput][1] block mimics the SelectOutput block and allows you to re-direct flow.
If instead you want to plit a flow, you use FluidSplit.Check the example models for each, they show nicely how to use them

Indeed, what I want is to split the fluid, but I would like the tank to have multiple outputs, not just two like in the FluidSplit. The problem is that these tanks are inside 'Distributor' agents, and each Distributor agent has a different number of clients that will receive the gas from these tanks

There is an example model showing how to do that. Can't remember the name, check all of the fluid ones
